# Is there a tool to know which lines from a CSS file has been changed?

Tags: css, version-control

For example, I'm working on a .CSS file and I handed it over to another person and that person made some changes.

When the file is handed back to me, is there a tool that I can run to help me know which lines in the CSS has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a diff tool. For Windows:
[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Linux and Mac OS X have the tool `diff`, which can be used via command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a command line diff most platforms have this.

There are lots of free, and paid for, comparison tools available, personally I like kdiff3, but the better option would be to use a version control tool such as [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), (hg), as you work and before handing anything over to anybody - then you can carry on working and still merge their changes back in even if you have also made changes.